# Core Data: Why reload data must be called to make my app work?

Tags: ios, core-data

I spend the whole night debugging a simple app. The app retrieves one image (yes one..intend to make my life easier) from web, and displays it in table view. I do that as a practice to learn Core Data. Before I fix it, the error message shows below:

> 2012-09-30 06:16:12.854 Thumbnail[34862:707] CoreData: error: Serious
>   application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of
>   NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after
>   the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in
>   the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of
>   sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo
>   (null)

Basically it's saying that **something goes wrong with FRC delegate methods**. At one hand, section number changes from 0 to 1. At the other hand, "0 inserted, 0 deleted". So how the section number can increase? That should not happen.. Hence the error.

I fix the bug by simply **adding `[self.tableView reloadData]` to my FRC setup method**. I got the inspiration from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7844903/359248), yet I don't quite understand it. The answer seems like too complicated and project specific. Could someone explain why adding `reloadData` can fix the bug? The answer might be an easy one, I hope so.

Key components of my app, if that matters:

- Use `UIManagedDocument` to establish the core data stack
- Create a helper method to download images from Flickr API
- In NSManagedObject subclass file, try fetch image from persistent store. If it's not there yet, insert it into MOC.

  ```
  - (void)setupFetchedResultsController
  {
      NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"BigImage" inManagedObjectContext:self.document.managedObjectContext];
      [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

      NSSortDescriptor *imageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"image" ascending:YES];
      NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: imageDescriptor];
      [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

      [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

      // Create fetch results controller
      self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.document.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

      self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

      NSError *error;
      if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
      {
          NSLog(@"Error in performFetch: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      }

      // Critical!! I add this line to fix the bug!
          [self.tableView reloadData];
      }
  ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fetched results controller tracks only changes to the managed object contents *after* the first fetch. These changes are then propagated to the table view using the delegate methods `didChangeSection`, `didChangeObject` etc.

But there is no automatic mechanism that the result of the initial fetch is sent to the table view. That is the reason why you have to call `reloadData` after `performFetch`.

However, there is a situation where this seems to work automatically. `UITableViewController` calls `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear` (if the table is loaded the first time). Therefore, if you set up the FRC for example in `viewDidLoad`, `reloadData` will be called in `viewWillAppear`, and you don't have to call it manually.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to know. You did me great help!